# unexpected change in variable while using function

Tags: function

I've written a simple code, but when I run the code `IniPopulation` will be changed to Population, Any reason this happens??? I'm a beginner .

```
Module Module1

Function SelectParents(ByVal Population As String()) As String()
    Population(0) = "Micheal"
    Population(1) = "Moses"
    Return Population
End Function

Sub main()
    Dim IniPopulation() As String = {"Saed", "Ahmad"}
    Dim population() As String
    population = SelectParents(IniPopulation)
    population(0) = "AZIZ"
End Sub

End Module
```